# How to tell phpdoc that 'return' type is the type of the param

Tags: php, phpdoc

Suppose we have such a method:

```
protected function proxy($obj) {
        return new Proxy($obj);
    }
```

`$obj` type can be different. But the returning type is the same as an param's one. For example if `$obj` type is `MyClass` then return type is `MyClass`. Is There a way to tell this to phpdoc?

Comment: Huh? That example would always return an object of type `Proxy`...

Comment: Generics provides a way to do it. Unfortunately php does not have generics, it's still in draft.

Comment: @Jon Stirling `Proxy` does not add methods nor properties. It does some stuff on the object. At some point you are right. Assuming that we found a way to tell returning type the same as an argument the phpdoc result will be `Proxy|{returnType}`.

Comment: That comment cleared up absolutely nothing :P

Answer (score 1):

Even if `Proxy` is only acting as a Decorator around whatever class the `$obj` instance is, the function *is still returning an instance* of the `Proxy` class.  Saying it still looks like and acts like the `$obj` class might be true, but technically it's still a `Proxy` instance... unless you're doing something weird with `Proxy::__construct()` that somehow does an explicit return of some other object, thus aborting the constructor before it could properly return its new `Proxy` instance.